# I want to create a drawing app for Android with features like draw,save,edit,delete,share

Tags: android, android-studio, drawing

I am trying to develop an app that allow user to draw, save, edit the already drawn image, delete already drawn image, share drawn image, and show all of the users drawing at one place

I have got the solution of drawing and saving and sharing part. However I have no idea about how to show all of the drawn image at one place and let user select to delete or edit it.

plz someone help me in my learning. Thanx in advance for the help.

Comment: you need to go through canvas, paints and many more

Comment: As i already mentioned that i have already achieved drawing saving and sharing all i want to show drawn images to one place in my drawing app.Like say that when my app open it should show all the previous drawn images and there will be a button for create/draw new image which will let user to draw and then save it.plus when user selects anyone of the drawn image for edit he should be able to edit

Comment: how can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You just save all the images in your database in two ways to store Base64 String of image or just save the bytes array and use it to manage all functionality like delete save or anything.

Comment: As i already mentioned that i have already achieved drawing saving and sharing all i want to show drawn images to one place in my drawing app.Like say that when my app open it should show all the previous drawn images and there will be a button for create/draw new image which will let user to draw and then save it.plus when user selects anyone of the drawn image for edit he should be able to edit